# is there any lib or widget in flutter that can be used to make widget like attached gif

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make widget like this in flutter but i am clueless where to start. I would really appreciate if anyone know anything to make a widget like this.

[enter link description here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kevalpatel2106/android-ruler-picker/master/.github/ruler-view-profile-demo-small.gif)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for, [rulers](https://pub.dev/packages/rulers):

```
    Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: RulerWidget(
                scaleSize: 100,
                scaleColor: Colors.yellow,
                indicatorWidget: Image.asset(
                                     'assets/marker.png',
                                     color: Colors.red,
                                     height: 25,
                                     width: 25,
                                   ),
                limit: 24,
                interval: 3,
                lowerLimit: 2,
                midLimitLower: 4,
                midLimitUpper: 7,
                upperLimit: 8,
                normalBarColor: Colors.grey,
                inRangeBarColor: Colors.green,
                behindRangeBarColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                outRangeBarColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: yes, but that lib doesn't support null safety

Comment: I think it's quite easy to migrate to null safety with this open source by your own, https://github.com/theshivamlko/rulers_flutter_package/blob/master/lib/src/RulerWidget.dart